# Database connection Error ..... cannot load driver class ... Datasource exception

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, datasource, spring-tool-suite

Application Properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RESERVATION?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.data-username=sam
spring.datasource.data-password=admin123 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/ spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/flightreservation2     
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
```

Application Main

```java
package com.sam.flightreservation;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication public class Flightreservation2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Flightreservation2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-03-03 17:42:47.183
>   ERROR 10344 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver       at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]      at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]      at
>   com.sam.flightreservation.Flightreservation2Application.main(Flightreservation2Application.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]

I have tried almost every site/YouTube, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Try removing property`spring.datasource.driver-class-name`

Comment: Did you add the MySQL Connector/J driver to the dependencies of your project, and are you sure it is version 8.0.x?

Comment: If i remove property spring.datasource.driver-class-name then its show error Access denied for user using password -no    BTW Thanks @user7294900

Comment: if i add MYSQL With version its show error ...so i addded Java connector dependency without version but still not working .......... Thanks For Suggestion @Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` will work for you with below dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [driver-class-name](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) with MySQL:

> The MySQL DataSource is known to be broken with respect to network timeout support. Use jdbcUrl configuration instead.

Also add datasource's user and password properties with valid values

Comment: If you specify driver-class-name, then you are not using a MySQL DataSource, your using the normal driver.